# What is the big O running time of the following code?

Tags: java

```
public static int Count( List<Integer> lst1, List<Integer> lst2)
{
    Iterator<Integer> itr1 = lst1.iterator();

    int count=0;
    while ( itr1.hasNext() )
    {
        Integer x = itr1.next();
        Iterator<Integer> itr2 = lst2.iterator();
        while ( itr2.hasNext() )
            if ( x.equals( itr2.next()) )
                count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

1. If an ArrayList is passed for lst1 and lst2.
2. If a LinkedList is passed for lst1 and lst2.

I go for both because for the fist while loop `O(n)` then the secong while `O(n)` and the if also `O(n) = O(n^3)`. I dont know if I am wrong or not?

Comment: n = list1.size m=list2.size  --> O(n*m) , you SHOULD use BRACES in this case for readability

Comment: @nachokk I disagree. Proper indentation is important. The braces play no role for readability here; if at all they are only relevant for correctness (but I’ve argued against this elsewhere as well).

Comment: @KonradRudolph really? second while where open and end is too clear? i have to think 5 seconds to realize where start and end

Comment: @nachokk I seriously don’t believe you. The indentation is *much* more visible than the braces (that’s why it’s so important to indent consistently, otherwise why bother?). Nobody seems to have any problem to read Python (although some object to its brace-less style – but not because of readability concerns).

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah it's true now that is with correct identation is easier to read, but what i was saying was that you have to discover where ends the second while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Big-O running time, assume lst1 has N items, and lst2 is initially empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255614/what-is-the-big-o-running-time-assume-lst1-has-n-items-and-lst2-is-initially-e)

Comment: @nachokk The indentation tells you that, if it's correct.

Answer (score 6):

It's `O(size(lst1)*size(lst2))`.  For all x<sub>i</sub> in `lst1`, you compare x<sub>i</sub> to every element in `lst2`.  In this case, it's more accurately `Θ(size(lst1)*size(lst2))`, since it's bounded both above and below by `size(lst1)*size(lst2)`.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt.. @steven gave a nice mathematical rep. The big O happening here is the multiplication of the sizes of lists providing to the method.

Because with each element in  the `list1` is comparing with each element in the `list2`..So that the loop runs for `SizeofList1*SizeOfLit2`.

Here is [beginner guide](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) with loops.Hope you will get it.